# Run 2 separate celery daemon on a same server

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, celery, daemon

I have one server with 2 projects, each for difference purpose but both need a to run scheduler task using celery.

I want to create to separate celery **daemon** on a same server, I try create to difference configuration file and run it with 2 difference process.

app1 tasks.py

```
from celery import task
@task()
def task_1(data):
    print("run task 1.")
```

app1 configuration file:

```
# Name of nodes to start, here we have a single node
CELERYD_NODES="w1"
# Where to chdir at start.
CELERYD_CHDIR="/usr/app1/task_scheduler/"
# Extra arguments to celeryd
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"
# Name of the celery config module.
CELERY_CONFIG_MODULE="celeryconfig"
# %n will be replaced with the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/tmp/%n.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/tmp/%n.pid"
```

app1, celeryconfig.py

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//'
CELERY_IMPORTS=("tasks")
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "amqp"
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = False
```

app2 tasks.py

```
from celery import task
@task()
def task_2(data):
    print("run task 2.")
```

app2 configuration same with app1 configuration except `CELERYD_CHDIR` and `CELERYD_NODES`. app2 celeryconfig.py is same with app1

My problem is when I add a new task on app1

```
from tasks import *
if __name__ == "__main__":
   ...
   task_1.apply_async(args=data, eta=t)
```

task_1 run as expected on app1 node but this task all so add to app2 node. Because node 2 did not have this function defined so a not_found function is raise on node2 log. It still can work but how Can I setup to make task_1 only send to app1 celery node only. I mean node 2 will not receive task_1 task.

Comment: I had a similar problem. I resolved it by changing the port for one of the workers and its corresponding redis daemon. See this: http://serverfault.com/questions/527311/celery-tasks-from-one-domain-appear-on-another-domains-django-admin-hosted-on-t

Answer (score 1):

Applications may be separated using *virtual hosts*

To create virtual hosts when using RabbitMQ you should see:
http://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html

The virtual host is the *path* part of the transport URL:

```
amqp://user:pass@host:port/vhost
```

The initial slash will be ignored so if your vhost is `/foo` you need
to include the extra slash, like this:

```
amqp://guest:guest@localhosts//foo
```

An example init script configuration starting two workers using two
separate apps:

```
CELERYD_NODES="w1 w2"
CELERYD_OPTS="-A:w1 proj1 -A:w2 proj2 --concurrency:w1=8 --concurrency:w2=4"
```

For more information about the `celery multi` options syntax see:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.multi.html

Then you just configure the app `proj1` to use a different virtual host from `proj2`.